How to apply scroll bar in bar chat if i have huge data
Bar Link: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html
i kept the below data
const labels = Utils.months({count: 24});
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 30, 40, 5, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 30, 40, 5, 65, 59, 80, 81],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
      'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
      'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
      'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

I need the scroll bar but it is adjusting the bars on that graph only
I need help on this issue..
Thank you in advance.
I tried with CSS and Java script the scrolling is coming but the width of the grids are chaning

You have to put the HTML and as well properly format the JS code snippet

Wrap with container and add overflow x

Give me 10 minutes

i couldnt add a gif for some reason
this is the code to solve it
add the wrapper div with smaller width and the property overflow-x :scroll;
    <div style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 400px">
      <div style="width: 700px; height: 400px">
        <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

and you should get your desired , have fun coding , cheers


